# Function Procedure in Java

Tags: java

Create a program that will ask the user to enter 3 numbers using for loop, then test the numbers and display it in ascending order.

Sample Input:
5
2
7

Sample Output:
2
5
7

I'm stuck with the testing procedure. I don't know how to test the numbers since the variable holding those numbers is just a single variable and inside the for loop

here is my sample code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class ascending
{
  public static void main(String args[])
   {

 for(int x= 0; x<3;x++)
 {
  String Snum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number");
  int num = Integer.parseInt(Snum);
 }

 <Here comes the program wherein I will test the 3 numbers inputted by the user and
   display in ascending order. I don't know where to start. :'( >
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to store your numbers somewhere. An array of ints is a good start, although you could use a collection such as an ArrayList.

```
int allNums[] = new int[3];
```

Then your loop stores the numbers into the array:

```
for(int x= 0; x<3;x++)
{
   String Snum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number");
   allNums[x] = Integer.parseInt(Snum);
}
```

Then you sort the array and print it.

Some obvious improvements:

- get rid of the magic number 3: `static final const int NUM_ITEMS = 3;`
- catch the `NumberFormatException` on parseInt

Answer (score 0):

here is a silly way to do it:

```
  static {
        int v1,v2,v3;
        for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
            if (i==0) {v1=Integer.parseInt(s);}
            if (i==1) {v2=Integer.parseInt(s);}
            if (i==2) {v3=Integer.parseInt(s);}
        }
        if ( v1 < v2 && v2 < v3 ) { System.out.format("%d %d %d", v1,v2,v3); }
        if ( v1 < v3 && v3 < v2 ) { System.out.format("%d %d %d", v1,v3,v2); }
        // 1 2 3
        // 1 3 2
        // 2 1 3
        // 2 3 1
        // 3 1 2
        // 3 2 1
    }
```

Comment: Your silly way contains an error. You probably want to assign the input to `v1`, `v2` or `v3` in the `for` loop.